# .avsc file downloading instead of .jar from Kaa Storm app log schema

Tags: logging, schema, apache-storm, kaa

As per the [kaa tutorial](https://www.kaaproject.org/iot-real-time-data-processing-in-storm-using-kaa/3/), it says -

> Put the log schema (*.jar file) library that you’ve downloaded from
>   Admin UI into ${KAA_SAMPLE_HOME_DIR}/storm-server/lib directory.

But when I download the log schema, it gets downloaded as an .avsc file and then the following command fails: `$ mvn clean install`

Although everything works fine if above documentation is not referred and instructions are followed straight from the kaa sandbox. Still I think, if documentation can be corrected then it would be easier to customize the client and server sdk, if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that there is small issue in terms of the picture shown in the tutorial and the step missed in the instructions given there.

Tutorial shows the following picture:
[Picture from Storm app tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl22m.png)

Now the admin UI looks like this:
[Picture from current Admin UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSy09.png)

The step which is missing in the tutorial is that one first needs to choose the export format as Java library and then download the library.